# SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' occuring in "For" loop IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting this error `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'` inside two "For" loops starting at the "of" portion in Internet Explorer.  Is there a workaround to resolving this issue?

```
for(item of workstationData.coPathColumns) {
    var builtId = '#icat-' + item;
    if(!!$(builtId)[0].innerText) {
        $(builtId)[0].parentNode.hidden = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ie does not support `for..of`

Comment: I see that, is there a workaround this for IE?

Comment: Do not use it seems like a good work around. :) Either you need to transpile your code or not use it.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by brk, IE doesn't support for of, look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) for details.

You can use `forEach` or a simple `for` loop. I prefer simple `for` loop for the reason that it is not `callback` based loop(Asynchronous), whereas, `forEach` takes a `callback` function.

```
for(let i =0; i< workstationData.coPathColumns.length; i++) {
    item = workstationData.coPathColumns[i]; //assuming item is defined before, otherwise use let item = ...
    var builtId = '#icat-' + item;
    if(!!$(builtId)[0].innerText) {
        $(builtId)[0].parentNode.hidden = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer does not support a `for ... of` loop.

As seen here: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browserkompatibilit%C3%A4t)

Furthermore I recommend you to check if a function or feature set is support for a browser you have to support, in this case Internet Explorer, check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)

Your code:

```
for(item of workstationData.coPathColumns) {
    var builtId = '#icat-' + item;
    if(!!$(builtId)[0].innerText) {
        $(builtId)[0].parentNode.hidden = false;
    }
}
```

can be transformed into a traditional `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < workstationData.coPathColumns; i++) {
    var builtId = '#icat-' + workstationData.coPathColumns[i];
    if(!!$(builtId)[0].innerText) {
        $(builtId)[0].parentNode.hidden = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it's nice to have, if you automate this process of "transpiling". Therefore have a close look at `babel`. Pasting your code into [babeljs.org](https://babeljs.io/repl)

Produces the following output - which should be equivalent to your `for...of` loop transpiled into `es2015-loose` standard:

```
"use strict";

for (var _iterator = workstationData.coPathColumns, _isArray = Array.isArray(_iterator), _i = 0, _iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : _iterator[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
  if (_isArray) {
    if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
    item = _iterator[_i++];
  } else {
    _i = _iterator.next();
    if (_i.done) break;
    item = _i.value;
  }

  var builtId = '#icat-' + item;

  if (!!$(builtId)[0].innerText) {
    $(builtId)[0].parentNode.hidden = false;
  }
}
```